# how to solder MEMS microphone to PCB at home?

Tags: audio, soldering, reflow, mems, mems-microphone

I would like to experiment with audio applications using MEMS microphone. 
The problem is i cannot think of a way to solder these microphones on a pcb as PCB prototype manufacturers that i know won't do re-flow soldering for a single board.

Comment: What is your question and what device are you considering?

Comment: @Andyaka I am trying to figure out ways to solder a microphone similar to this onto a pcb https://www.pololu.com/file/0J299/SPM0404HE5H.pdf

Comment: There are very many tutorials on the web for doing prototype reflow soldering, using hot-air tools, toaster ovens, electric hotplates, etc. You need to do some research and then come back here if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to buy a hot-air reflow station, e.g. [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10706). Chinese-manufactured ones are reasonably inexpensive, and some are of good enough quality for prototype/home use.

You might also consider [dead-bug prototyping](http://makezine.com/2012/10/08/a-fine-example-of-dead-bug-style-circuit-wiring/) with some 30-gauge wire or so and a good quality hand solder with a fine tip. This involves turning chips upside down and soldering pins directly to parts or using wire, without necessarily using a board (you can solder the wires to a PCB or a copper-clad board of some kind if you want). This can require fine wire and a lot of skill for parts with small, fine-pitched pins.